# how to use iphone simulator 5.1 in xcode 4.6.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I install xcode 4.6 in my mac and I want to use simulator 5.1 in my xcode. I could put iphone simulator 5.1 in my new xcode but when use xcode this simulator dont show in my xcode.
**I want run my project with iphone simulator 5.1 not iphone 6.1 simulator.**
I have xcode 4.4.1 and 4.6.2 setup.
this is my simulator and xcode picture :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have the 5.1 simulator but you're targeting your app for the 6.1

Select your project -> Targets -> Summary tab -> And set the Deployment Target to 5.1

Answer (score 1):

Go to the xcode menu, preferences, downloads. You will see the option to download older simulators.

Comment: I going to this address and I see iphone simulator 5.1 is install but When I run my project on top of xcode dont showing iphone simulator 5.1

Comment: Are you sure your base version for the project is not set to 6.1?

Comment: my friend how I know what is my base version the project?

Comment: See the answer by Mat. It gives the location, where the base version is set. By base version, i meant the deployment target